# Transferring Bitmap object over HTTP Webrequest C#/ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap

I have a client which, every 1 second, sends an HTTP post request to a certain ASP page and gets a response.
So far i've transferred only strings.
I need to transfer an image which is being created on the client (C#) side, to the web application, and display it on the site.

I've realized that the `StreamWriter.Write()` can write any object, but the `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` returns only string.

So... How can I transfer the bitmap in the most efficient way?

Best regards,
Cybrus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've missed the gist of your question, if so I apologize, you are asking how to read a binary stream to the end. Try this static method:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

private const Int32 standardBufferSize = 0x10000; //64k
private static Func<long, byte[]> createBuffer = x => (byte[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), x);

/// <summary>
/// Reads a <code>System.IO.Stream</code> to it's end using indicated buffer size.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="st"><code>System.IO.Stream</code></param>
/// <param name="bufferSize">Buffer size in bytes</param>
/// <returns><code>System.byte[]</code></returns>
public static byte[] readFullStream(Stream st, Int32 bufferSize)
{
    var _locked = false;
    Monitor.Enter(_lock, ref _locked);
    if (bufferSize <= 0) { bufferSize = standardBufferSize; }
    try
    {
        var size = 0;
        var continueRead = true;
        var buffer = createBuffer(bufferSize);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (continueRead)
            {
                size = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (size > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                }
                else
                {
                    continueRead = false;
                }
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (_locked) Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HttpHandler to return the image. You need to do something like this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class BitmapImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       // you can pass desired dimension as querystring params if the image
       // needs to be with dynamic dimensions.
       int width = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["width"]); 
       int height = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["height"]);

       using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width,height))
       {

            /*code to generate the bitmap image*/

            using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream()) 
            {
                //Save the bitmap in the desired format
                bitmap.Save(mem, ImageFormat.Png);
                mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // set the desired content type for the output
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/png"; 

                mem.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream, 4096);
                context.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; }
}
```

After that you can call it in this way:

```
<img src="YourHandlerName.ashx?width=10&height=10"/>
```

If you are using MVC and you don't want to use handler, you can do something similar in controller action method and skip the creation of handler.

Comment: One of us didn't understand the other. (i think at least)
I'm willing to send a bitmap file from StreamWriter and read it from StreamReader.
The bitmap making process is being made in the client (C# Console application) and the reading is being made on the server(ASP.Net web application).

Is that what you understood from my question and i didn't understand the answer? :S

Thanks a whole lot for the help.